# Ruby/RoR: calling original method via super()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a RoR app, I want to specialize ActiveRecord's update_attributes() method in one of my models, extracting some of the attributes for special handling and passing the rest of them to the original update_attributes() method.  The details:

```
class Premise < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def update_attributes(attrs)
    attrs.each_pair do |key, val|
      unless has_attribute?(key)
        do_special_processing(key, val)
        attrs.delete(key)
      end
    end
    # use original update_attributes() to process non-special pairs
    super.update_attributes(attrs)
  end
  ...
end
```

The call to super.update_attributes(attr) raises an error:

```
undefined method `update_attributes' for true:TrueClass
```

... which makes me suspect I really don't understand the super keyword in Ruby.  What am I missing?  Specifically, how do I call the original update_attributes() method?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want:

```
super(attrs)
```

That will call the original method, passing attrs as an argument to it.

As it is now, you're trying to call update_attributes on the "true" value returned by the original update_attributes.

Comment: In this case, the arguments on `update_attributes(attrs)` and `super(attrs)` are the same. You can simply call `super`, with no parentheses.

Comment: @LBg Ah, thanks, good point. I also corrected a bit at the end of my answer about that; I'd originally written that the code in the question was called update_attributes with no arguments, but that's not correct.

Answer (score 52):

In Ruby super is a special case where parenthesis do matter...

Calling `super` without parameter (nor parenthesis) in a method of a subclass calls the same method in the super-class (or its ancestors if the superclass does not define it) with all the parameter passed to the subclass method. So, here, you could have written simply super.

Calling `super()` calls the superclass (or ancestors) method without any parameter (assuming this method accept no parameters...)

Calling `super(...)` with any combination of parameters calls the superclass method, passing it the paramaters

Comment: Man this is super useful. How about to explicitly send same received parameters and the method is `method(param, *otherargs)`?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a better use for alias_method_chain:

```
def update_attributes_with_special(attrs)
  attrs.each_pair do |key, val|
    unless has_attribute?(key)
      do_special_processing(key, val)
      attrs.delete(key)
    end
  end
  update_attributes_without_special(attrs)
end
alias_method_chain :update_attributes, :special
```

Comment: I contemplated that.  That begs the next question: when would you subclass and when would you chain?

Comment: @FearlessFool: Inheritance is usually a code smell in Ruby without a compelling argument for shared internal state/resources.  The benefit of using alias_method chain is eating your cake and having it too.  You get a class with a modified update_attributes() and preserve the non-modified functionality as well.