# Override Rails' active record method on has_many collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I find myself in the position of [this SO post author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146974/ruby-ror-calling-original-method-via-super) in which I need to override ActiveRecord create/accessor methods in certain classes, which are extended by a custom module. I've plumbed for this:

```
module ClassMethods

  @ar_methods = [ :create, :find_by, :find_or_create_by, :update, :where ]

  @ar_methods.each do | ar_method |
    define_method(ar_method) do | attributes |
      process_attributes!(attributes)
      super(attributes)
    end
  end

  def process_attributes!(attributes)
    # process some attributes ...
  end
end
```

This works fine, so that if the `Bar` class is extended by this module, then

```
Bar.create(raw_attributes)
```

creates a record in the database with suitably processed attributes.

However, a problem arises when my `Foo` class `has_many :bars`, so that

```
foo.bars.create(raw_bar_attributes)
```

creates a `bar` belonging to foo with the raw, unprocessed attributes. I could always resort to

```
foo.bars << Bar.create(raw_bar_attributes)
```

which works, but I'd like to avoid setting a trap for unwary colleagues if I can help it. So how could I override these methods? ActiveRecord's internals are opaque to me, so I'm not entirely sure where to start.

Thanks in advance.

(For further context on my actual problem: say, for the sake of concreteness, that I have a `Person` class, but that for some inexplicable reason many moons ago a convention was adopted that the `person`'s actual age was doubled before saving it to the database, so that instead of writing `Person.create(name: name, age: age)`, throughout the entire code base we have

```
person = Person.new
person.name = name
person.age = 2 * age
person.save
```

with similar gymnastics for dividing by 2 after reading from the DB. But further suppose that multiple objects are blighted by this problem, and that the largest affected table in our production DB is several hundred GB on disk, and that multiple legacy services are constantly writing to and reading from this table using this convention so that it is highly impractical to fix the root cause (and we have no idea at all why the convention was adopted, so are mildly concerned that something unexpected would break horribly if we did attempt to fix it). This is why I want to encapsulate the awfulness in a module that can be shared across the afflicted classes. )

Comment: Do you really need to muck about with the persistence methods? Can't this be solved by custom setters/getters or the typecasting?

Comment: Custom getters/setters are part of my module - I'm including instance methods as well as extending the class methods. But sometimes this means writing 10 lines when one will do, as in my example above (but with more instance variables in reality) and the code is horribly bloated.

Comment: If the logic is essentially the same but the naming is just different you can use metaprogramming to create the setters/getters.